# Stop ARC releasing an object while it is idle

Tags: objective-c

I am having a problem with memory management in objective C. Ive been reading through the [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) but I cannot find a solution to my problem with the possible exception of abandoning ARC altogether and managing the memory manually.

Here is the problem:

I have a `Controller` class that Ive made, that holds information on what to do at specific times.

The `Controller` class tells the rest of the app to play a video (for example). The video plays fine. When the video finishes playing, the `Controller` class knows what to do next.

Unfortunately the `Controller` class is released and deallocated by ARC almost as soon as the video starts playing. So by the time the video ends, the app calls the `Controller` class to see what it should do next, and the whole thing crashes. I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` because the class is no longer in memory.

I get that ARC is releasing my `Controller` class because after it has told the video to start playing, its not doing anything. But I want to keep hold of that class until I need it again.

I am declaring this class as a property, like so:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) Controller * controller;
```

But despite this, ARC keeps releasing the class as soon as its not doing anything.

**EDIT:**

Ive moved this property into the App Delegate. But ARC is still releasing it. I cant turn this into a Singleton, as I need the potential to have multiple copies of this class.

## How can I stop ARC releasing objects when I dont want it to??

## Is it possible to keep an object in memory while its not doing anything?

Is this possible at all? Or should I abandon ARC and just do memory management manually?

Comment: where are you defining the *controller property ?

Comment: In the detailViewController of a Master/Detail view app.

Comment: "I am declaring this class as a property, like so: ..." - I will ask stupid questions: do you assign value to this property? Which class owns this property?

Comment: Yes, the `Controller` class is assigned, and accessed so that it tells the app to play a video. Then it is released. I want to stop this happening. The video is being played in the detailViewController which also holds the `Controller` - so the parent class should still be in memory.

Comment: create a strong property reference to it in your appdelegate and see if the problem persists, it would only be released by arc if the number of strong references to the object reaches 0

Comment: I think you should refactor the code and move state information to separate class (probably this will be a some kind of data model) and app delegate should store this information. Trying to extend lifetime of view controller can lead to strange errors.

Comment: ok, Ive moved it into the AppDelegate, but I still get EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors. I dont want to create a Singleton because I need multiple copies of this class. HOW DO I MANUALLY STOP ARC RELEASING OBJECTS??

Comment: is it even possible? is this why nobody can give me a straight answer?

Comment: A strong reference will stop ARC from releasing things. If that's not fixing the issue, then it's very likely that your crash is not due to ARC releasing things.

Comment: @Jimmery: You could implement an empty `dealloc` method in the Controller class (*yes*, that is allowed with ARC!) and set a breakpoint there. Then you will see exactly when the object is deallocated. That might help to locate your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a singleton pattern so that `Controller` looks after its own lifetime and exists app-wide.  This shared instance will exist from when it's first requested until the app terminates and ARC will not release it arbitrarily.

Controller.h:

```
@interface Controller : NSObject

+ (Controller *)sharedInstance;

@end
```

Controller.m:

```
#import "Controller.h"

static Controller *_instance = nil;
static dispatch_once_t _onceToken = 0;

@implementation Controller

+ (Controller *)sharedInstance {
    dispatch_once(&_onceToken, ^{
        _instance = [[Controller alloc] init];
    });
    return _instance;
}

// You could add this if you want to explicitly destroy the instance:
+ (void)destroy {
    _instance = nil;
    _onceToken = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your controller is getting dealloc'ed when the detailViewController is dealloc'ed. Hence, you must move the handle of your controller and define in it the any of the following :

1. MasterViewController or your application's RootViewController
   OR
2. AppDelegate
   OR
3. Create a singleton as answered by "trojanfoe"

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this case several times when working with `UITableView`s. I created a private `@property (strong) id *yourObjectRetain` and assigned my object to it. An array for multiple objects will also work.

Comment: I need more than this. ARC is releasing my objects even though they are strong.

Comment: It shouldn't release them as long as there is at least one reference to them. This is the reason why I put them into this instance variable. Just to hold one reference.

Comment: The object I keep losing is a property of another object that is a property in my AppDelegate. The parent object is still alive and there - so there is a reference to the object I am losing. Is there a way to force ARC to stop releasing my object?

Comment: Have you looked into this: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html ? Take a closer look at "Singletons". They may help you solving this...